# How to update Main Component state from Other Component React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making a login page. So i declare a State with islogin. Now i did check a condition. If islogin false then it return the login page otherwise it will goto the route Components.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import {AppNavigator} from './route-components/route';
import Login from './Components/login/login'

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);



export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      signin: false
    }
  }


  render() {

    if(this.state.signin){
      return (
        <AppContainer />
     );
    } else {
      return (
       <Login islogin={this.state.signin} change={this.change}/>
      )
    }

  }
}
```

login.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Button, WingBlank, WhiteSpace, InputItem } from 'antd-mobile-rn';


export default class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            signin: this.props.islogin
        }
    }

  render(){
    const {change} = this.props;
    return(
        <View style={style}>
            <InputItem  type="text" placeholder="Enter Username"  > 
        </InputItem>
            <WhiteSpace />
            <InputItem  type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" > 
         </InputItem>
            <WhiteSpace />
            <Button style={{margin: 10}} onClick={change}>Login</Button>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Now trying when I hit the login button then it will change the app.js state and switch to the Route component

Comment: Can we see your `this.change` method in `ÀppComponent`. This is where you should update your state after checking for correct Auth details ofcourse

Comment: I dont actully add any auth. I just did true false. And also not write anything at this.change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to declare a callback method which will change the state variable in app.js and pass the callback method in login component and just call the method from onclick event.
here is a code sample fo app.js

```
userLogIn = () => this.setState({ signin: true });
<Login userLogIn={this.userLogIn} change={this.change}/>
```

and in Login.js just replace this

```
<Button style={{margin: 10}} 
   onClick={this.props.userLogIn}>Login
</Button>
```